# Ler arquivo xml remoto

Tags: php, xml

Como posso ler um arquivo xml que é gerado online, é um arquivo gerado pelo meu fornecedor, http://www.shoplivre.com.br/hayamax/haymax.php. Ele é gerado somente através do meu site mas como posso ler ele e gravar em um banco de dados?

Comment: Qual lingaguem está usando? [tag:c#]? [tag:php]?

Comment: Estou utilizando php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clayton,

O PHP contém uma maneira de ler arquivos de XML nativamente, sem outro biblioteca. [Existe documentação aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.xmlreader.php), em português mesmo, da classe `XMLReader`. Não importa se o arquivo XML vem de um site ou se vem de um arquivo físico.

Comment: bom dia então estou utilizando o xmlreader como vc me indicou, mais estou tendo o seguinte problema se o arquivo está na mesma pasta ele funciona, mais quando o arquivo é para pegar através da URL da erro. 
`$file = 'cross-docking.xml'; $xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($file);

`código`$file = 'http://webmax.hayamax.com.br/crossdock/servlet/CrossDockingServlet.class.php?action=crossDockingPrice&customerId=10363&compress=0&canal=C1';`

$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($file);

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com.o erro q recebeu por favor

Comment: da erro 500, a minha hospedagem não mostra a linha que está o problema, no arquivo de log deu 2015-08-12 15:53:59 W3SVC6 PLESKCW0022 186.202.119.39 GET /hayamax/teste.php - 80 - 200.193.178.177 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:39.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/39.0 - - www.shoplivre.com.br 500 0 0 1579 333 67485

Comment: Coloquei esse URL no meu browser (http://webmax.hayamax.com.br/crossdock/servlet/CrossDockingServlet.class.php?ac‌​tion=crossDockingPrice&customerId=10363&compress=0&canal=C1) mas não dá um arquivo XML ... será que precisaria de algo mais?

Comment: Além disso, se recebe um 500, normalmente diz que algo está errado no *servidor*, ou seja, um problema com o próprio site.

Comment: mais com te disse se mudar para $file = 'cross-docking.xml'; ele funciona o erro só acontece quando estou com a url configurada. $file = 'http://webmax.hayamax.com.br/crossdock/servlet/CrossDockingServlet.class.php?ac‌​tion=crossDockingPrice&customerId=10363&compress=0&canal=C1';

Comment: Esse url só funciona no meu domínio, http://www.shoplivre.com.br/hayamax/haymax.php (nesse link da pra vc testar gerar o xml) em outro domínio não vai funcionar porque é liberado no servidor do meu fornecedor o ip do meu domínio.

Answer (score 2):

Clayton, com a url que gera o xml, o que você tem que fazer é usar uma biblioteca que faça requisições rest para baixar o xml para a sua aplicação e após isso você processa o xml.

Comment: Sabe de alguma biblioteca que faça isso? Ildyone

Comment: Você vai ter que pesquisar, porque isso vai depender também de qual versão da linguagem que esta usando assim como o sistema operacional. Não esqueça de votar na resposta.